# Add-on for Google Chrome for inserting Furigana to Web Pages

Tags: discussion, kanji, furigana

I'm new to Japanese language, I don't know much Kanji. I need a browser add-on (an extension or a userscript) for Google Chrome which will automatically insert Furigana over all Kanji characters.

In the past, when I was using Mozilla Firefox, [Furigana Inserter](http://code.google.com/p/itadaki/) + [HTML Ruby for Firefox](http://htmlruby.codeplex.com/) combined were doing quite a good job. Now I need an as robust solution as that to use with Google Chrome. So that I can learn new Kanji characters while doing my daily stuff on the net.

I tried using [Furigana Injector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cbahnmcliajmanjkaolemjelphicnein), but it didn't work. I don't know if did something wrong, may be I needed to install a companion add-on (like HTML Ruby in Firefox) for it to work. It is not well documented.

Can you please offer me a solution on this matter?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I guess Rikaichan is not a good solution for you?

Comment: Occasionally Furigana Injector will time out talking to the server, but it's usually just temporary, I find it works awesome usually!

Comment: @Nicolas Raoul: I'm already using Rikaichan (actally using its Chrome version; Rikaikun). I need an extension which shows the readings without pointing on the Kanji with mouse pointer.

Comment: @mletterle: Furigana Injector fails connecting to server, and the script writer refuses to write an offline version. Please see the issue #63 (http://code.google.com/p/furigana-injector/issues/detail?id=63).

Answer (score 2):

There is a Japanese site which does this:
http://www.hiragana.jp/

e.g. try:
http://trans.hiragana.jp/ruby/http://www.yahoo.co.jp/
(shows up as nice ruby for me in Firefox, don't know how it will work with Chrome).

Alternatively if you're having trouble getting Ruby to show up properly, does Rikaikun do the "d" option for hiding English definitions like Rikaichan does? That works for me to provide a sort of "pop-up furigana" when I need it.

Comment: Thank you. It is good to know this site. However, I need an automated solution, without framing every website into another.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another tool that i've found to be amazing. it's called "Riraikun" and it's an add-on  for mozilla firefox and an extension for google chrome. what it does is when you put your cursor over any japanese character, whether in kanji or hiragana, it looks up the definition and places it in in small blue pop up box. hard to explain, but it makes sense if you use it. i recommend it a lot! 
google chrome link: https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/jipdnfibhldikgcjhfnomkfpcebammhp

mozilla firefox link:https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/rikaichan/I'm sorry if you use a different browser, but from what i know those are the only two browsers that support it.
Chrome Add link:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jipdnfibhldikgcjhfnomkfpcebammhp

Comment: I know and I already use Rikaikun. I want something that inserts Furigana over kanji, as I stated in my question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using 'IPA furigana' and it looks decent:  https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ipa-furigana/jnnbgnfnncobhklficfkdnclohaklifi/related